# How to add google map polygon using gmap3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I'm trying to add polygon into an existing map. The page already contains gmap3 plugin and a map of a location.

```
<section  class=""><div class=''><script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { 
            map('#map1', '1660 Lincoln St 24th Floor, Denver, CO', 12); });
 </script>

<section class='map' id='map1'></section></div></section>
```

How should I include a [polygon](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/polygon-40) into it?